# Why doesn't My phone recognize my SD card?

Tags: sd-card

My phone ( Trend plus) doesn't recognize my SD card. It's been working for almost 2 years now, I don't know what happened, did I damage it somehow, I don't know.

Comment: Is that SD card works in other devices such as another mobile or in PC.. ??

Answer (score 1):

Try your SD card in another phone or a computer. If it works, then it's probably your phone. Try an SD card that you already know is working in your phone and see if it reads it. If it doesn't, then it's definitely your phone but it could be the SD slot itself or a software problem. If another card works in your phone and your card works in other phones, then I don't know what to tell you; use a working card, I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your SD card probably suffered Heat death: try in computer (with adapter)
If you get nothing; it requires an expert to [Maybe] get data off of it.

I have had SD cards die suddenly on me too.